# Textfield focus node staying focused

Tags: android, flutter

I have been following this article https://medium.com/saugo360/https-medium-com-saugo360-flutter-using-overlay-to-display-floating-widgets-2e6d0e8decb9 to add an autocomplete box below my search bar, everything seems to work except that the overlay box stays open all the time even if I close the hamburger menu that the textfield is in. The overlay will stay open even when going onto another page. Which makes be think the focusnode isn't working as it should. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
class TagSearchBox extends StatefulWidget {
  SearchGlobals searchGlobals;
  TextEditingController searchTagsController;
  TagSearchBox(this.searchGlobals, this.searchTagsController);
  @override
  _TagSearchBoxState createState() => _TagSearchBoxState();
}

class _TagSearchBoxState extends State<TagSearchBox> {
  final FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();
  OverlayEntry _overlayEntry;
  @override
  void initState() {
    _focusNode.addListener(() {
      if (_focusNode.hasFocus) {
        this._overlayEntry = this._createOverlayEntry();
        Overlay.of(context).insert(this._overlayEntry);
      } else {
        this._overlayEntry.remove();
      }
    });

  }
  OverlayEntry _createOverlayEntry() {
    RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject();
    GelbooruHandler booru = widget.searchGlobals.booruHandler;
    var size = renderBox.size;
    var offset = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);

    return OverlayEntry(
        builder: (context) => Positioned(
          left: offset.dx,
          top: offset.dy + size.height + 5.0,
          width: size.width,
          child: Material(
            elevation: 4.0,
            child: FutureBuilder(
                  future: booru.tagSearch(widget.searchTagsController.text),
                    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done && snapshot.hasData){
                        return ListView.builder(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return ListTile(
                                title: Text(snapshot.data[index]),
                                onTap: (() {
                                  widget.searchTagsController.text = snapshot.data[index];
                                })[![enter image description here][1]][1]
                            );
                          }
                        );
                      } else {
                        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                      }
                    }
                ),
            ),
        ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: TextField(
          controller: widget.searchTagsController,
          focusNode: this._focusNode,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText:"Enter Tags",
            contentPadding: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15,0,0,0), // left,right,top,bottom
            border: new OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(50),
              gapPadding: 0,
            ),
          ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Overlay on texfield]

[image: Overlay after burger menu closed]
[image: Overlay on new page]

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by putting my entire home scaffold inside a gesture detector with

```
onTap: (){
          FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
        },
```